# D3 data not showing all the elements

Tags: d3.js

I have the following code

JS:

```js
var cities = [
    { name: "Moscow", x: 585, y: 565 },
    { name: "Kiev",   x: 735, y: 765 },
];
```

HTML:

```html
<svg .....>
// My SVG code
</svg>

<script>
// d3.select("svg").append("text").text(cities[0].name).attr("x", cities[0].x).attr("y", cities[0].y).attr("font-size",18).attr("fill", "black");
// d3.select("svg").append("text").text(cities[1].name).attr("x", cities[1].x).attr("y", cities[1].y).attr("font-size",18).attr("fill", "black");

d3.select("svg").data(cities).enter().append("text").text(function(d) { return d.name; } ).attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; } ).attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; } ).attr("font-size",18).attr("fill", "black");
</script>
```

I'm new to D3. I was trying to convert my commented out code, which works, to some code which iterates over the array I have defined. However, I only get the last element printed with the non commented out code. Why and how to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a `selection` using `selectAll` and *then* bind data to it before you can start the `enter` phase.

What you want is something on these lines:

```
d3.select("svg")
    .selectAll('text.city-name')
    .data(cities)
    .enter()
  .append("text")
    .classed('city-name', true)
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; } )
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; } )
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; } )
    .attr("font-size",18)
    .attr("fill", "black");
```

Working example: [<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/ejrez/).

---

In your case, what is happening is that the existing `svg` element is getting bound to the first element in `city` and then the second city's `text` element gets created in the `.enter()` phase and is added to the `body`.

To understand how `.data` joining works and how `.select` and `.selectAll` differ, I think [thinking with joins article](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) is a great place to start.

Comment: This example doesn't work. However, I did work out the answer, although I'm not sure at the moment why it works.

    d3.selectAll("svg")
    .data(cities)
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; } )
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; } )
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; } )
    .attr("font-size",18)
    .attr("fill", "black");

You have to change select to selectAll, plus remove the 'enter' directive. SelectAll because I guess it's only selecting one element otherwise.
Removing .enter I'm not sure why this make a difference.

Comment: @ShaneCook Updated the answer. If you `.selectAll('svg')` and then `.append('text')`, then you create two `text` elements which will append to the `body`.

Comment: My version worked only for two elements. The answer, at least the demo version, is correct and works with larger elements. Many thanks.